# Xpath: How to select value of parent note in xpath if child exists

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I try to build a html table with javascript out of a xml

Therefore I need the value of a parent element from a different ancestor called "name" with xpath, if a child with e.g. //host exists

I need only the channel name out of the xpath:

```
"/serverConfiguration/channels/channel/name"
```

where the child

```
"/serverConfiguration/channels/channel/sourceConnector/properties/listenerConnectorProperties/host"
```

exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of XPath it seems you just want a predicate `/serverConfiguration/channels/channel[.//host]/name` or `/serverConfiguration/channels/channel[sourceConnector/properties/listenerConnectorProperties/host]/name`.

Comment: @th_lo, the first attempt is trying to transcribe your verbal description 'I need the value of a parent element from a different ancestor called "name" with xpath, if a child with e.g. //host exists' to XPath, the second attempt is using the paths you showed in the rest of the text.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks. I also tried to fill empty nodes as empty values in a table element but I guess that should I ask in another question...